# Store, retrieve and update a sequence number (datatype int) in a single row of a table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to store, retrieve and update a sequence number in a single row of a table with a schema like:

```
ID (int)
LookUp(varchar)
SeqNum(int)  --business logic dictates the SeqNum is constrained to a particular range, say 1300 to 7600
```

To me this looks like the clickercounter guy at a ball park using a clicker to ticks one off for each person that goes by. I want each person to have a unique number. I want multiple clickercounter people to use the same clicker and I don't want any missed values.

So far my approaches have either resulted in a deadlock condition leaving the table inaccessible or me scratching my head wondering about how to structure a stored procedure that calls a stored procedure that has a transaction to lock the record, read it, update it, commit the transaction, and unlock the record

In pseudo code I tried something like

From within a stored procedure:

```
Call getnum stored procedure
sproc getnum
begin trans
    select current seqnum into a variable from Seqtbl where lookupval = 'nosebleed'

update Seqtbl.seqnum++ where lookupval = 'nosebleed'
end trans
```

I thought of adding a bool column `bLock` and then having the getnum stored procedure check if the value = false then update the lock (bLock=true) followed by a read, update, and update the lock (bLock = false) without using a transaction. But I am not convinced that ill conceived timing of multiple processes could not interfere with each other.

I do see others using identity columns to achieve similar solutions but it seems that these approaches require one table per LookUp (from the sample schema above) value.

Does anyone suggestions, strategies used to solve similar problems, guidance, or links to send me to school on the important aspects of SQL Server needed to understand a solution to this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get rid of deadlocks if you use just single stament:

```
declare @id int

update Seqtbl
set @id = seqnum, seqnum = seqnum + 1
where lookupval = 'nosebleed'
```

The bigger problem here is that you said that there cannot be holes in the sequence. If your actual transaction can be rolled back, then you'll have to include the sequence fetching to the same transaction to be rolled back as well and that's probably going to cause you a lot of blocking, depending on how much many calls there are.

If you're using SQL Server 2012 or newer, you should also look into sequence object, but that's not going to solve the issue with missing values either.

Comment: To prevent locking between different lookupval values, it might help to have only one row per page, assuming you only have small amount of lookupvals. You should be able to archive that by having a filler column in the field so that only one row fits to a page.

Comment: Perfect!  Simple, elegant and it works (so far with two processes competing for the next sequence value it looks great.  Although I did put this code in the calling sproc, omitting from the scenario the second sproc.  I guess I was overthinking the problem...

Comment: A primary key on lookupval is important as that will allow row-level locking and avoid deadlocks.

Comment: I would upvote your solution but sadly my reputation does not permit...I did want to say thanks though

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Why are you using a sequence for this?  Your analogy to the click-counter "guy" would not suggest a sequence or identity value.  Instead, it would suggest inserting the click with an identity column and/or precise creation date.  A query can then be used to assign a sequential value when you need it:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (order by id)
from table t;
```

You can then use arithmetic to get the value in the range that you want.

Comment: really knowing about existence features prevents imposing extra costs to warehouse. +1

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I need to go learn about how to use the over statement.